# Preciso selecionar ranges concatenando addresses em VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, range

Tenho um sub em VBA que faz diversos cálculos para chegar em uma lista de address de ranges 
    listaAddresses = "$A$1, $H$3,$V$1,$M$16,$A$21,$B$13,$H$88..... $T$44"

Com essa lista preciso selecionar todas as ranges. Então tentei - 
    Range(listaAddresses).Select

No entanto, quando tenho mais que um certo numero de Ranges, o VBA e o VB (tentei em ambos), dão erro e não selecionam nenhuma celula.

Comment: Olá colega. Eu não consegui reproduzir o problema que você diz ter. Em um teste rápido defini a variável `listaAddresses = "$A$1,$H$3,$V$1,$M$16,$A$21,$B$13,$H$88,$T$44"` e então chamei a seleção fazendo `Range(listaAddresses).Select`. Funcionou, como você pode ver nesta captura de tela: http://imgur.com/a/CYWmw Edite a questão para explicar melhor ou faça um [mcve] que reproduza o problema.

Comment: Acabei de conseguir. Fiz um loop de listas de addresses e usei Union para concatenar todos os Addresses

Comment: O problema acontece depois de 255 ranges separados. Acho que deve ser algum limite de string.

Comment: Bom, ok. Talvez tenha algum limite mesmo no número de intervalos que se pode passar para o método `Select` (apesar [da documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) não especificar nada). Você deveria ter deixado claro que esse era o problema na pergunta. Sugiro editar a questão pra colocar essa informação (de que ocorre um erro - aliás, indique qual erro ocorreu - quando tem mais de 255 intervalos separados). Dai também sugiro que você mesmo crie uma resposta com a sua solução (a ideia do Union é bem boa!). Se fizer isso, ganha meu +1 na pergunta e resposta. :)